# How to move GameObjects using the world position in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

So, I'm trying to figure out how to write a script which will be able to detect when game objects are in a certain world position, to transform those game objects and move them up by say 1.

Hope that makes sense, if not please ask and I'll try my best to explain in further detail. Really would appreciate any help.

Comment: This is too broad - it's generally expected that you attempt to write your own code first, and only pose a question on Stack Overflow if you run into problems with it that you can't solve; this site isn't meant to deliver code written from scratch. To get you started, look into [`Transform.Translate()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html) and consider using a trigger collider (or [`Physics.OverlapSphere()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html)) to detect objects entering a particular area.

Answer (score 4):

```
void updateGameObjectsMatchingPosition(float x, float y, float z)
{
    // Please try to use something more specific like GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("CoolTag");
    var gameObjects : GameObject[] = GameObject .FindObjectsOfType(GameObject) as GameObject[];

    for(var i = 0; i < gameObjects.length; i++) {
       var position = gameObjects[i].transform.position;
       if(position.x == x && position.y == y && position.z == z) {
           //Do something with the position of this object.
           gameObjects[i].transform.position = new Vector3(x + 1, y + 1, z + 1);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah this works, but unless you're enforcing a discretized world, you should probably check to see whether the position is within some small distance of the position you're looking at rather than hard equals.

Comment: Alternatively, [Kd-trees](http://unitycoder.com/blog/2013/03/26/kdtree-find-nearest-object/) can be used to efficiently search for your objects. You should consider this if you have too many objects.

Comment: Agreed with code11 and lucasdavid, use this only for test purposes, try to use something more performant, asking just for GameObjects is too lazy and too expensive.

Comment: A collider/physics-based approach is the simplest Unity-specific solution for the kind of detection needed here, but since the OP hasn't made any clarifying edits/comments to their question it's not clear whether that (or any of the existing answers) meet the OP's requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Attach this script to your game object.

```
[SerializedField] Vector3 _designatePosition;
IEnumerator MoveUp() {
    var speed = 5 * Time.deltaTime;
    var targetPosition = transform.position + new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
    while (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetPosition) > 0.01f) {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, speed);
    }
}

void Update() {
    if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, _designatePosition) < 0.01f) {
        StartCoroutine(MoveUp());
    }
}
```